# Как получить список всех столбцов всех таблиц пользователя, начинающихся с прфикса с подчёркиванием?

Tags: sql, oracle

Как получить список всех столбцов всех таблиц пользователя `DWL`, которые начинаются, например, с `DEK_`?

Answer (score 2):

Надо экранировать нижнее подчёркивание в имени столбца.

Без указания в параметре `escape` символ для экранирования не определён. Поэтому, определите любой символ, который не может встретится в имени столбца.

Вот так:

```
select *
from all_tab_cols
where owner = 'DWL' and column_name like 'DEV\_%' escape '\'
```